# Ocaml parser "unterminated action" error

Tags: parsing, ocaml, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I am new to OCaml and I am trying to create a Parser for a specific language using a parser generator - ocamllex, ocamlyacc. When i'm trying to compile my **parser.mly** file, I am getting the following error:

Error (with mark at =) :

```
File "parser.mly", line 94: unterminated action
| id = IDENTIFIER { identifier id }
;
```

The following is an extract from the parser.mly file:

```
%{
  open Ast

  let identifier name = {
    Identifier.name = name;
  }
%}

%token <int> INT
%token <string> IDENTIFIER

%start monitor
%type <Ast.Expression.t> monitor

%%

ident:
  | id = IDENTIFIER { identifier id }
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocamlyacc does not support giving names to the parts of a rule like this. You'll either need to use `$1` etc. or switch to Menhir, which does support this feature.